# Waterline / sails-mongo Type _getPK error

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm working on a table using waterline and I just change on field form string to a relation ship and now when I run it I get the error `[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  TypeError: Cannot read property '_getPK' of undefined`

Before (item model):

```
attributes: { store: 'string' ....}
```

Changed to (item model):

```
attributes: {store: {model: 'state'} ....}
```

And under state model:

```
attributes: { items: {collection: 'item', via: 'store' }}
```

Thanks in advance guys

---

Edit:

I've downgraded to `sails-mongo@beta` and everything is working. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What version of sails-mongo and waterline?